# Any way of optimizing joins between 2 databases with different collations?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I'm creating a query for a report where we must do a cross database join. Unfortunately the fields we have to join on have two separate collations - "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS". The join is very slow between these and is really impacting the speed of the report - is there any ways of optimizing this? Is changing the collation to match wise and/or difficult?

The join portion of the query is below

```
INNER JOIN EDE.dbo.DeliveryDetail D
              ON D.DeliveryNoteNo COLLATE database_default = Consignments.CustomerReference COLLATE database_default
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can add columns to tables, you can try persisted computed columns, and index those. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DeliveryDetail ADD DeliveryNoteNo_Collated COLLATE whatever PERSISTED;

CREATE INDEX IX_DeliveryDateNo_Collated ON dbo.DeliveryDetail(DeliveryNoteNo_Collated);
```

You're basically pre-baking converted versions of your fields once on insert (and kept updated for you automatically), and indexing those.

There are two really big drawbacks. First, these are new columns in your table: they'll take up more space, the indexes will take up more space, and if your apps are doing inserts without explicitly listing their column names, their inserts will fail.

Second, if the app's connection options aren't set correctly, your delete/update/insert operations can actually fail. NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT has to be set OFF, and ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER must all be set to ON. You'll definitely want to test for this in development first, and for bonus points, check sys.dm_exec_sessions in production to check everybody's session settings.

For more info:

- [Books Online page on computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)
- [MSSQLTips demo on using computed columns](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/)

Comment: I want to add that a consistent collation standard is the best practice for all objects in a SQL instance (and perhaps enterprise) but it's a real pain to remediate collations. This is a good workaround for a targeted issue but a mass collation change would ideal.

Comment: @DanGuzman in theory, yeah, but I've seen plenty of cases where folks had to take apps from different vendors and different in-house developers, and make them work on a single SQL Server. (sigh)

Comment: Yes, the real world is ugly. I have this problem with over 10 different collations used throughout the organization.

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices here. The best approach depends on the nature of the data itself (what it is and how it is used) and how much control you have to change either table. Since no information was provided regarding the data or level of ability to make changes, I have outlined below the decision making process I would go through to determine the optimal approach:

1. The *ideal* solution is to forgo Collation issues in the first place. Joining on string columns is, more often than not, a bit tricky. IF these databases are in your control, then you would gain the most performance (while also eliminating any potential for the current problem) by converting the values to a numeric type. A column name of `DeliveryNoteNo` implies that it is some type of code.

   If this is a code and the values are finite, then it would be best to move the possible values into a lookup table with a `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT` clustered PK. This will, in most cases, actually also reduce the size of the table, which helps performance. But the JOINs will definitely be faster. On the downside, this approach could very well require help from development as it might change the nature of an input field, etc, but is usually worth the effort :-).

   If the values are not finite, then if they are at least purely numeric, altering the column to be a numeric type would be best.
2. If it is not possible to change the two columns in the JOIN to be a numeric type (whether to store a lookup ID or the current value), then if the values are an alphanumeric code, your next best option is to use a binary Collation -- in your case it would be `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`). This requires that if the values do have any letters in them, that they are always cased the same. But this would still be far better than either of the two current Collations as they both allow for casing differences *and* linguistic equivalences, both of which slow down comparisons. Those features of those two Collations are very important and helpful when needed, but a huge performance hit when not needed.

   If the data is always cased the same in both columns, then you can try either specifying the binary Collation on the `WHERE` condition as you are presently doing (though it only needs to be added to one side, not both), or if you do control both tables, then altering the columns to use the binary Collation. Of course, doing this would depend on how the column is used in other queries (i.e. are there any queries that sort on either of these columns).
3. If other queries sort on either of these columns but the data is still cased the same between the two columns (also assuming that no queries attempt mixed-case comparisons), then the next best option is to try a case-sensitive Collation to at least eliminate a large portion of the comparison rules that you aren't using: `Latin1_General_CS_AS`. Again, you can try specifying once in the `WHERE` clause (e.g. `ON D.DeliveryNoteNo = Consignments.CustomerReference COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) or, the better approach here would be to ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` for both columns.
4. If you can't do any of the above, then the next simplest thing to try would be to force the Collation of the column that is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` to be `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. I would try via the `WHERE` condition first, just in case the `DATABASE_DEFAULT` for the database in which you are running this query is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

   The better option would be to just `ALTER` the column that is using the `SQL_` Collation to instead use the non-`SQL_` Collation (and then remove the `COLLATE` keyword(s) from your query). Again, this requires testing to make sure that other queries are not JOINing on the Column presently using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` Collation that might break.
5. If you can't make any of the physical changes mentioned above, and if specifying a binary Collation (or a case-sensitive Collation if binary won't work) on there `WHERE` condition either is not an option or does not improve performance to an acceptable degree, *then* you should add a Persisted Computed Column as Brent Ozar has [suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162426/30859).